# How to represent combinations of plus and minus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, notation

Just wondering if there is a shortcut for representing the following:
$$x=1+i,1-i,-1+i,-1-i$$
I know that you can do:
$$x = 1\pm i,-1\pm i$$
But can you use something like:
$$x = \pm 1 \pm i$$
NOTE: I know the example above just gives $x = 1+i, -1-i$, but I just wanted to provide an example

Comment: I would write $ x = 1+i, 1-i, -1+i, -1-i$ (with maybe a line break). No need to complicate things.

Comment: I don't think that $1\pm i, -1\pm i,$ can be regarded as either ambiguous or confusing.  However, while technically, a case could be made that $\pm 1 \pm i$ is similarly unambiguous, some may find it confusing/ambiguous.

Comment: Overkill: $x\in\{\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi a}\mid a=k+1/4,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Answer (score 3):

Do you think $$(-1)^x \left( 1 \pm i \right) \\ x\in\{0,1\}$$ is a nice idea?

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: let $z=1+i$ and

$$x \in \{z , \bar z, -z , - \bar z \}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another variation is
\begin{align*}
x^4=-4
\end{align*}

Comment: The question asked for a method to combine plus and minus. It never came to me that + and - could sum up to zero ;). Now there is no need of sums!

Comment: @SteelCubes: Yes, thanks to the fundamental theorem of algebra we can encode the wanted information as precisely the zeros of a polynomial of fourth degree. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Writing $$x = \pm 1 \pm i$$
is ambiguous as it could either mean $x \in \{1+i,-1-i\}$ or the intended $x \in \{1+i,1-i,-1+i,-1-i\}$. You can make it unambiguous by specifying (in words) that the $\pm$-signs can be chosen independently. I've also seen $x = \pm 1 \pm' i$ to make the independence of the $\pm$-signs explicit in the notation, but I'm not sure that's very common.

Comment: I've used things like $\pm^a(x\pm^b y)$, but only for personal calculations, not public consumption. ;)