# How to write $(\pm x,+y)\;,\;(\pm x,-y)$ in a compact form?

Tags: notation

I want to show these duplets in a compact form
$$(\pm x,+y)\quad,(\pm x,-y)$$
Then, is it clear to use
$$(\pm x,\pm y)$$
or this only considers upper and lower signs together?

Comment: A good question! Does $(\pm x,\pm y)$ denote two points, or four? For me, it is not at all clear.

Comment: @charmin $|x|=\pm x,|y|=\pm y\\ (\pm x,\pm y)\to (|x|,|y|)$

Comment: sometimes, clarity is much better than compactness.

Comment: @Khosrotash $|x|$... a single value... is not equivalent to $\pm x$ which denotes two values.  The set $\{(\pm 1, 2)\}$ is commonly interpreted as being the set $\{(1,2),(-1,2)\}$ while the set $\{(|1|,2)\}$ is interpreted only as the the set $\{(1,2)\}$

Comment: If you insist on writing this, perhaps write it as $\{(c_1 x, c_2 y)~:~c_i\in\{-1,1\}\}$ which extends easily to $n$-tuples.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4045621/42969

Comment: @JMoravitz: "If you insist on writing this": the OP doesn't insist on anything, they just want to know the best way to denote the set $\{\{x,y\},\{x,-y\},\{-x,y\},\{-x,-y\}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer $\pm(\pm x, y)$, but do not see this idiom widely-used. To the contrary, students sometimes ask if it means the same as $(\pm x, \pm y)$, whereupon we have to have the Discussion about Which Choices of Sign are Intended.

Not that you asked, but  $\pm(x, y)$ is (to my eye) preferable to denote the two points with same sign.